# Delete row in nested Telerik MVC grid

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik, nested

I face a problem - the controller method gets a NULL argument (key field value) from the nested (detail) view. 
What did I miss?

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<mCustomer>()
    .Name("CustomerGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerId).Title("CustomerId").Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerName).Title("Customer");
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerAddress).Title("Address");
        columns.Command(comand =>
        {
            comand.Edit();
            comand.Delete();
        }).Title("Command");
    })
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.CustomerId))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("CustomerListAjax", "Customer")
            .Insert("InsertCustomer", "Customer")
            .Update("EditCustomer", "Customer")
            .Delete("DeleteCustomer", "Customer")
    )
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("customer_onRowDataBound"))
    .DetailView(detail => detail.ClientTemplate(
        Html.Telerik().Grid<mProject>("<#= CustomerId #>")
            .Name("Projects_<#= CustomerId #>")
            .DataKeys(k => k.Add(p => p.ProjectId))
            .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    //columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectId).Visible(false);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectName).Visible(true).Title("Project").Width(180);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectCustomer).Width(340).Visible(false);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.IsForcast).Visible(true).Title("Is Forecast").Width(150).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='chkForecast' disabled='disabled' <#= IsForcast? \"checked='checked'\" : \"\" #> /> ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
                    columns.Bound(p => p.RateMode).Visible(true).Title("Rate").Width(80);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.IsVacationPaid).Visible(true).Title("Vacation Paid").Width(100).Width(150).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='chkIsVacationPaid' disabled='disabled' <#= IsVacationPaid? \"checked='checked'\" : \"\" #> />").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
                    columns.Bound(p => p.IsHolidayPaid).Visible(true).Title("Holiday Paid").Width(100).Width(150).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='chkHolidayPaid' disabled='disabled' <#= IsHolidayPaid? \"checked='checked'\" : \"\" #> />").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
                    columns.Bound(p => p.IsSickDaysPaid).Visible(true).Title("Sickness Paid").Width(100).Width(150).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='chkSickDaysPaid' disabled='disabled' <#= IsSickDaysPaid? \"checked='checked'\" : \"\" #> />").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
                    columns.Bound(p => p.StartDate).Title("Start Date").Width(100).Width(130).Format("{0:d}");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Probability).Title("Probability").Format("{0:N3}").Width(100);
                    //columns.Bound(p => p.AccountManager).Title("Owner").Width(100).Width(150);
                    columns.Command(comand =>
                    {
                        comand.Edit();
                        comand.Delete();
                    }).Title("Command").Width(200);
                }
             )
            .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                .Select("ProjectListAjax", "Customer", new { CustomerId = "<#= CustomerId #>" })
                .Delete("DeleteProjectAjax", "Customer")
                .Insert("InsertProjectAjax", "Customer", new { ProjectCustomer = "<#= CustomerId #>" })
                .Update("EditProject", "Customer")
            )
        //.ClientEvents(e=>e.OnDataBound("project_OnDataBound").OnEdit("project_OnEdit"))
            .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
            .RowAction(row =>
            {

            })
        //.Selectable(s=>s.Enabled(true))
            .Filterable()
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
            .Editable(e => e.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true).Enabled(true))
            .ToHtmlString()
     ))
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable()
    .Filterable()
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    .Editable(e => e.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true))
    .Pageable(builder => builder.PageSize(10))
    .Groupable()
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(500))
    .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
    .Render();
%>
```

Controller method:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult DeleteProjectAjax(mProject project)
{
    _manager.Projects.DeleteProject(project);
    return View(new    gridModel(_manager.Projects.GetProjectListAjax(project.ProjectCustomer)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been a problem with editing in nested grids in the official release, which we fixed after a major refactoring of the client-side editing. You can try out an [internal build](http://www.telerik.com/account.aspx) or wait for the official service pack next week (27.09. - 01.10.).

Comment: Alexander, could you please to estimate final date or please provide link to

Comment: I can't get model in controller Delete method: it's null

Answer (score 0):

I can't get model in controller Delete method: it's null

<% Html.Telerik().Grid()
        .Name("CustomerGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerName).Title("Customer").Width(250);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerAddress).Title("Address").Width(250);
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator") == true)
            {
                columns.Command(comand =>
                {
                    comand.Edit();
                    comand.Delete();
                }).Title("").Width(200);
            }
            columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerId).Title("CustomerId").Hidden(true);
        })
        .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.CustomerId))
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                .Select("CustomerListAjax", "Customer")
                .Insert("InsertCustomerAjax", "Customer")
                .Update("EditCustomerAjax", "Customer")
                .Delete("DeleteCustomerAjax", "Customer")
        )
.Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Editable(e => e.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true))
        .Pageable(builder => builder.PageSize(15))
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(500))
        .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
        .Render();
    %>

here is controller

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [GridAction]
        public ActionResult DeleteCustomerAjax(mCustomer Customer)
        {

```
        _manager.Customers.DeleteCustomer(Customer);
        return View(new GridModel(_manager.Customers.GetCustomerListAjax()));
    }
```

Who could tell me what was missed?